# Django template render into self-contained file

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm attempting to render a Django template into a self-contained HTML file. For instance, I would like CSS style sheets that are `<link>`-ed to be expanded into `<style>` sections. Same deal with Javascript files. This way the HTML file is entirely self-contained.

Is there an option in Django or an extension that will do this? If there isn't, what's the best approach for achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to [django-compressor](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest). It's pretty easy to configure and use.

Quote from [docs](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/):

> The compress template tag supports a second argument specifying the
>   output mode and defaults to saving the result in a file. Alternatively
>   you can pass ‘inline‘ to the template tag to return the content
>   directly to the rendered page, e.g.:

```
{% load compress %}

{% compress js inline %}
<script src="/static/js/one.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">obj.value = "value";</script>
{% endcompress %}
```

> would be rendered something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
obj = {};
obj.value = "value";
</script>
```

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thanks for the answer.